# Check or change default value for domain of attribute in feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, subtype, domains

I want to check (and potentially change) the default value for an attribute domain in a feature class.  However, when I access the feature class properties pop up box and click the Subtypes tab, everything is "greyed out" and I am unable to scroll down to the Field Name I need in the Default Values and Domains box to check the default value.  I am working with an enterprise geodatabase.  Is this a permissions issue?  Or should I be doing something differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as though there are a couple points of confusion...

The default value for a given field is set under the feature class properties, on the "Fields" tab, not Subtypes:

- Select the field in the upper box
- Look at the lower box which indicates what the Default Value is and also what geodatabase domain is associated with the field
- If you cannot type anything in to the "Default Value" property box, then it's likely there is a schema lock preventing changes. Alleviate all locks and try it again.

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding your issue. Let us know if this is it!

Comment: Thank you, Matt!  You were right - I was definitely confused.  Thanks again for helping me sort it out!